# javascript - get HTML attribute value from a JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON request result for a blogger post.

```
// API callback
posts(
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "entry":
    {
        "title":
        {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "Vimeo Embed Video Post"
        },
        "content":
        {
            "type": "html",
            "$t": "<span data-format=\"video-post\"><\/span><iframe allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"281\" mozallowfullscreen=\"\" src=\"\/\/player.vimeo.com\/video\/107469289\" webkitallowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"500\"><\/iframe> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br \/>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br \/>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br \/>consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br \/>cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br \/>proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        },
    }
});
```

Inside the `"content"` you can see there is a `<span data-format="video-post"></span>`. I want to get value from `data-format` atrribute with javascript.

Comment: Do you want to get mentioned value inside `posts` function?

Comment: Yes, I want to get value from `<span data-format="..."></span>`, and yes it is inside the `posts` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Try this...

```
function posts(data) {
   var formatData = $(data.entry.content['$t']).data('format');
}
```

**Update #2**

In case if your data object, or any of it's properties/subproperties might be not defined, here is safer version:

```
function posts(data) {
   var formatData = data 
      && data.entry 
      && data.entry.content 
      && data.entry.content['$t'] 
      && $(data.entry.content['$t']).data('format') || '';
   if (formatData!='') { //If has value
      // ... have something to do about it
   } 
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jevgenig/qL3o8d9r/)

Comment: Yes, now it looks good for me, +1. And just to mention: `content['$t']` is correct and appropriate way to get value by key `$t`, but `content.$t` seems to work aswell.

Comment: Well, can we add a `if` function? since the `<span data-format="..."></span>` not automatically generated by the blogger so it will not available for every JSON request. I mean the script will only get the value when `data-format` available in JSON, if not, the result should be return `blank` or `null`.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Please check JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jevgenig/qL3o8d9r/

Comment: variable "formatData" is defined inside function "posts" and you are trying to use it outside. Just move document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = formatData; into the body of function, as last row, like that: http://jsfiddle.net/jevgenig/78thgfu9/1/

Comment: but the `formatData` value still not printed in the document

Comment: It's because in that example, function posts was executed two times, with valid and invalid formatData values. Invalid was the last one. I've removed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jevgenig/78thgfu9/2/ and it works now

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(variable.entry.content['$t']).data('format');
```

where variable is a parameter of your post method.