# Best way to automatically update paragraph contents from javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON object that contains a value I want to automatically update on my webpage. The JSON object is being retreived from a google sheets file using:

```
function getData() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1r56MJc7DVUVSkQ-cYdonqdSGXh5x8nRum4dIGMN89j0/1/public/values/R29C4?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'importGSS'
    })
}

var obj;
getData().done(function (data) {
  obj = data;
});
```

(Thanks to user Andy for this!)

I can access the value by `obj["entry"]["content"]["$t"]` but I am not sure how to add this value to my paragraph element so that it automatically updates when the value changes in the object.

Could someone explain the best way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: The general way: `$('p').html(obj["entry"]["content"]["$t"]);`

Comment: I have definitely seen this object's structure [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159217/javascript-get-html-attribute-value-from-a-json-request) 15 minutes ago...

Comment: OK great I've got it now. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```js
function getData() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1r56MJc7DVUVSkQ-cYdonqdSGXh5x8nRum4dIGMN89j0/1/public/values/R29C4?alt=json-in-script&callback=importGSS',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'importGSS',
        success: function(data) {
            // p being the element that you want to put your data in
            $('p').html(data["entry"]["content"]["$t"]);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes this could work. The only issue is I have around 50 values to put into seperate divs in the actual spreadsheet so idealy I would want to asign each value to a variable with a semantic name in the javascript first to make the code easier to read.